# Why does compilation through MSBuild take so much longer than through the IDE?

Tags: delphi, msbuild

Here is my bat file.

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\rsvars.bat"
msbuild.exe C:\Work\Project1.dproj /t:Rebuild /p:Config=Debug;Platform=Win32
```

This seems to work well; however, it's taking 12 minutes to build. That same configuration/platform combination takes 2 mins 30 secs when doing a full build in the IDE. I've been unsuccessful in locating the cause of the slowdown. Any ideas or settings I should be looking at?

EDIT: I was using IDEFixPack 5.3 and getting build times ~2.5 mins. Removing IDEFixPack results in 12 min builds in the IDE as well.

Comment: How can we reproduce this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. Today is my first time playing with msbuild so I don't know enough about this to provide a reproducible scenario. I can try with a sample app, but the conditions are going to be much different than my commercial application which has 3,560,000+ lines. I wasn't sure if there were known compiler switches in msbuild that I should be looking at.

Comment: I forgot a detail regarding the IDE. I use IDE fix pack, but I've never seen a performance difference anywhere near this when it's enabled vs. disabled although it probably does account for a very small portion of the difference.

Comment: I tried 2 other projects that are considerably smaller: 6,200 and 386,000 lines and both of those are taking approximately the same amount of time as in the IDE. I don't know what it is about my big project that's slowing it down in order to provide a reproducible scenario.

Comment: I have no idea, sorry, but upvoted since it's an interesting question. Good luck!

Comment: what happens if you run the delphi compiler directly from the command-line? i.e. dcc32.exe Is it fast like the IDE or slow like MSBuild?

Comment: Remove IDEFixPack and try compiling again in the IDE. See if that is relevant. You need to try to get some more diagnostic information.

Comment: Actually IDEFixPack is very plausible. It does add some compiler performance improvements. You could try to persuade msbuild to use Andy's fastdcc to see if that also speeds things up.

Comment: I would guess that there are some parts in the search path that point to a network drive that does not exist. The IDE checks this once and caches a lot. MsBuild might try this path for each file it encounters. But that's just a guess.

Comment: @David Heffernan - Holy Crow! We've been using IDEFixPack for a year or two because builds were taking ~5 mins and they dropped to 3.5-4 mins after installing it. A couple of hardware upgrades later and I'm at 2.5 mins for a build. Removing IDEFixPack and the build takes 12 mins 6 secs (rough timing on iPhone stopwatch). Dang. Well, I guess that answers my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per David Heffernan's suggestion I removed IDEFixPack and I see the same 12 min build times as I do with msbuild.

Comment: +1 In that case you should be able to use Andy's fastdcc to speed up your command line builds

Comment: Awesome. I wasn't aware of that tweak. I'll be sure to investigate. Our build process has become somewhat complicated. We use FinalBuilder which works well, but the Delphi build actions seem to lose the auto-increment version number setting and the version numbers get out of whack. I have a utility to update the dproj version settings before calling msbuild. I've found your posts on StackOverflow most useful for making the switch. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have been of some little help!

Answer (score 1):

I guess there are some packages for which the IDE somehow can find the compiled dcu's in the path and MSBuild can only find the source.

Doesn't MSBuild output a compilation log that you can examine or post here?

Comment: Why would that happen? The whole point of the new msbuild based build is that the command line and IDE builds use identical search paths. I do feel that this would be better as a comment.